# How necessary is it to Encrypt database password field

Tags: database-design, encryption, passwords, security

I heard that for security issues it is advised to keep the password field encrypted in the database.

In case of my website only I can access the database. And I have no problem with me viewing others passwords as per our web site policy.

Does this applicable to my website too OR there is some other security reason behind telling this.

Comment: what is the name of your company's stock? thx

Comment: Dont worry..you wont get interested after knowing that..

Comment: Salt+Hash, don't encrypt. It can (and usually does) fall into the wrong hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) is that nobody - not even the user themselves - should be able to see passwords, and that they should not be stored in the database in a way that allows them to be retrieved. This is because there are many ways in which this data can get lost - an administrator may print out a report, and leave it on their desk; an attacker might be able to use SQL injection to run database queries; someone may be able to break into your building and steal a backup tape.

Many customers use the same password on multiple sites - so if your sites is the weakest link, you may be exposing them to risks on other sites if they have re-used their passwords.

The recommendation is to use a cryptographic technique called "hashing", which takes the plaintext password and turns it into a meaningless string; there's no way to reverse the hash, which means that even if I stole the hashed password, I couldn't work out what the original, plain text was.

Hashing the same string twice gives the same hash - so when someone logs in, you hash their plaintext password, and compare it to the hash in the database.

The OWASP link provides further information on this topic, including "salting" the hash.

Comment: Let me give you a real world example just to press this point. My cell phone provider, T-Mobile, has an online site to manage/buy parts/add lines to your account. I forgot my password and hit the "Forgot Password" button, they immediately sent my plaintext password to my phone via text message without giving warning. My phone was sitting on my office desk where I have 5-6 co-workers standing by, and my password was flashed on my phones LCD for a couple minutes before I was able to come back to my office. Texting me was just the tip of the iceburg, storing it plaintext is what pisses me off.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't store any passwords in the database at all, encrypted or otherwise.

Instead, **store a hash**. When user tries to log-in, calculate the hash on the password the user entered and compare it with the hash stored in the database.

Unfortunately, plain hashes are susceptible to so called "rainbow" attacks. If an attacker gets hold of your table, (s)he could just pre-calculate hashes of the whole English<sup>1</sup> dictionary or even of all combinations of characters up to certain length, generating so called **"rainbow table"**, and then rapidly compare it to the database table for hashes that match. Some of your users are bound to use weak passwords that can fail under this kind of attack.

To prevent rainbow attacks, don't hash the password itself. Instead hash password + salt. The **salt** is a random, user-specific string that doesn't need to be more secret than the hash itself<sup>2</sup>. This introduces variations in hashes, so the attacker can no longer use the same rainbow table for all users. The attacker would in effect have to generate a new rainbow table for each user (and his/her salt), hopefully making it prohibitively expensive.

Lack of salting contributed to the massive security breach of LinkeIn this year. Quote from [this New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/11/technology/linkedin-breach-exposes-light-security-even-at-data-companies.html?pagewanted=all&_moc.semityn.www):

*"Salting passwords, security experts say, is Security 101 — a basic step that LinkedIn, eHarmony and Lastfm.com all failed to take."*

Of course, that should be just the last layer of a multi-layered defense, the layer designed to make attacker's life harder after they have already read your database. You should try everything in your power to prevent this from happening in the first place, including prevention of SQL injection, strict separation of tiers, proper database security, firewalls, regular patching etc...

---

*<sup>1</sup> Or some other human language of interest.*

*<sup>2</sup> But should, ideally, be stored separately, behind a well-defined Web service API for example.*

Answer (score 1):

You should always hash passwords. The users have no reason to trust you, and you have no way of knowing whether or not your database has been compromised. With a question like this, I can only assume you have a basic understanding on website security. We live in the days where companies like Sony, the US Govt, Banks, etc are getting their databases hacked weekly. If you think you are exempt to this, then you should post it at the registration as to let your users know that you don't care about their privacy.

There is no reason whatsoever that you should be able to read one of your users passwords.

To implement password hashing, you should take the password during registration and hash it before storing in database. Then when a user logs in, you should hash the password, and then compare the hash to the hash in your database. If they compare, then its the same password.

Also, remember to salt the passwords. This means that if you have a password of "test" and hash it, if a users on another site has the password "test" the two hashes are the same and they can figure out the password based on previous hashes. Salting is like adding extra data to the password prior to hashing, so "test" in your database might actually be "test123" and whenever someone types a password, your PHP automatically appends "123" to it. This way when comparing hashes from your site to another site, the hashes for the same password are not identical.

Comment: Well i did not mean that i read their passwords..In the site i am talking the forms are there where the admin can view the users password too..Me being the admin and get to know user's password is the same thing as looking at them in database..So i was worried whether there is some more reason to this.

Comment: I am also wondering how it is prone to hack..unless and untill my db is out my control..And i know that anyone's site can be hacked..it is a matter of who is doing it..

Comment: I get what you are saying, but that is really bad practise. There is no reason any admin should know users passwords. Admins should be able to CHANGE passwords, but they shouldn't need to know the old one to do this.

Comment: Well i am managing this site after tons of developer have worked on..No control over the implementation done in past.

Comment: Just imagine that StackOverflow used the same practices, some pissed off admin gets your password and logs into your website admin panel. From there he can see the passwords of every users on your site along with their email address. You shouldn't user the same password for everything, but most people do. Now this guy has access to all your users email and from there can request password resets from their Bank Accounts, Facebook, and any other site. If you are recording passwords in plaintext and someone gets hacked, you should be held liable.

Comment: I understand your point..my question was what are the security measures behind this..not ethical logic i would say..But you are correct in your point, which is obvious...One more point..what if my users have knowledge of this..then how much is it important

Comment: It should really only take a couple lines of code. when registering, encrypt the password. When logging it, encrypt the password before comparing to the database.

Comment: Just a niggly point - but don't encrypt the password, because encryption can be reversed. Hash the password. 
Also, to see what happens when this goes wrong, google for the Sony or LinkedIn password exposures.

Comment: I am not sure of the question you are asking. Do you want to know how to implement it, or what?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you think you are the only one that can access it. Security should be implemented in layers so if one fails there's always another behind it.

Passwords should always be hashed and salted.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one point to the already provided good answers. The hash algorithm should be **slow**, because otherwise it's easy to brute-force until you find a match. An off-the-shelf GPU can calculate about 8 Giga of combinations, so you can try a whole english dictionary in less than a millisecond!

That's why you should use **Bcrypt** to hash your passwords, it was designed especially for hashing passwords. It has a cost factor that allows to adapt to future (and therefore faster) hardware.