# How to securely implement SQL queries in a Java desktop app

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am creating a Java desktop application that generates and stores users passwords on a database.

My question is: ***what is the most secure way to implement SQL queries in the application?***

Surely it is not secure to have the queries within the source code. My work around would be to store the db file locally, but I would prefer to store the data on an external server.

So how do I implement SQL queries in a swing application without having them embedded the source code.

Comment: Have the swing application talk with a server (using RMI, web services, or whatever), and execute the SQL queries in the server code.

Comment: If you have the option of moving the data around, why not have a web service maintain it for you on the server side ? Access to the database is a bigger concern than access to the SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to protect query text. You may have concerns regarding logging of the parameters used by query. If you store raw passwords in the database this is a problem. So I would recommend to not store [raw passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530634/how-necessary-is-it-to-encrypt-database-password-field) in the first place.

I would elaborate a bit about embedding SQL into Java code. If you application works with database you need to make calls to database and this means execution of SQL statements. The only way to avoid this is to delegate this work to another application so your application will use not SQL but some custom protocol/API and that application will execute SQL queries on its behalf.

You may what to store SQL separately from Java code but this not due to security concerns but mainly because of need to more properly structure you application. That is main driving forces to not embed SQL into Java code are code readability, performance, maintenance and code reuse.

It is a common practice to use ORM when accessing database. In this case it not uncommon that your application do not have SQL code at all but access database through ORM API. In hibernate for example the query may look like

```
User user = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .add( Restrictions.eq("name", userName) )
    .uniqueResult();
```

And even if you need to execute some SQL query which is not directly supported by ORM of your choice the SQL text itself is usually stored in some accompanied xml file.

Please note that in the latter case though technically SQL is not embedded into Java code it is still reside in one of your application packages.

Comment: Rarely is encrypting passwords a better alternative than [salting and hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: I understand that concept entirely thank you for your response. Is it safe to have SQL code within the Java source code that connects to an external database where other users of the software would also have their details stored. For example The user would enter their name and generate an encrypted password, this password would then be uploaded to the database. So for me to have SELECT and UPDATE statements within the source code would this be a good idea?

Comment: I've added more information regarding embedding SQL into Java code.

Answer (score 2):

> Surely it is not secure to have the queries within the source code.

I have never seen an SQL *query* that was sensitive. Typically you accept the sensitive data from the user (e.g. password input into Swing field) and use this to populate an existing parameterized query, e.g.

```sql
UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE username=?
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how do you want to execute something in your application without implementing it. I just simply dont understand your approach. You are probably want to register new user or something, and you dont't want to reveal your database structure in any way, am I right? You can't do something like that to directly operate on DB (by sql) and not code it into app.

**Solution**:
Create dedicated REST API for your needs. All db operation handling would be on server side (hah, you need server - can be simple apache hosting for php) so no DB structure revelations etc. All you would need to do would be send command to server with appropriate data - username and password. For maximum security you should use SSL for comunicating with API.

Thank you.